# Find the limit of the weird sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find limit of sequence $a_n,n\geq1$ given by the recurrence:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+a_n}}, a_1>0.$$
All my attempts have been unsuccessful. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice for any $n > 0$, if $a_n > 0$, then $0 < a_{n+1} = a_n\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+a_n}} < a_n$. Start from the given condition $a_1 > 0$, we can deduce $a_n$ is a monotonic decreasing sequence bounded from below by $0$. The sequence $a_n$ will converge to some $\alpha \ge 0$.

If $\alpha > 0$, then for any $p > 0$, we have

$$\frac{a_1^2}{\alpha^2} \ge \frac{a_1^2}{a_{p+1}^2}
= \prod_{n=1}^p \frac{a_n^2}{a_{n+1}^2} = \prod_{n=1}^p \left(1 + \frac{a_n}{n}\right) \ge 1 + \sum_{n=1}^p \frac{a_n}{n} > \alpha\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{1}{n}$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^p \frac{1}{n}$ diverges like $\log p$ for large $p$,
this inequality will be violated for sufficiently large $p$. This mean $\alpha$ cannot be positive. As a result, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \alpha = 0$$